# Solving Integrals over Jordan curves

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I have this function:

$$
\int_{L} \frac{dz}{z^{4}+1}
$$
$$L: x^2+y^{2}=2x $$

The question is how to calulate the integral. The solution uses the Cauchy Teorem:

$$f(a)=\frac{1}{2\Pi i} \int \frac{f(z)dz}{z-a}$$

$$\frac{1}{z^4+1}=\frac{1}{(z-\sqrt{i})(z+\sqrt{i})(z^2+1)}$$
we set a to be -i
$$\frac{f(z)}{z-\sqrt{i}}$$
so:
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z+\sqrt(i))(z^2+1)}$$

and so 
$$\int_{L} \frac{dz}{1+z^4}=\int_{L} \frac{f(z)}{z-\sqrt{i}}=i2\Pi f(\sqrt{i})= \frac{1}{(-\sqrt{i}+\sqrt{i})(z^2+1)}=1/0 = \infty$$

What have I done wrong, how do you solve these ones ?!

Comment: $z^4+1=(z-\sqrt{i})(z+\sqrt{i})(z^2+1)$ is wrong, third factor should be $z^2+i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^2+y^2=2x$ is equivalent to $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$, so this gives us the circle of radius $1$ centered at $(1,0)$. The solutions to $z^4+1=0$ which lie in this circle are $\frac{1}{\sqrt2} \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt2}i = z_+, z_-$. Each pole has order $1$, and so the residue of the pole at $z_0$ is given by 
$$\mathrm{Res}(f, z_0) = \left((z-z_0)f(z)\right)\big\vert_{z=z_0}$$
This gives us
$$\mathrm{Res}(f, z_+) = -\frac{\sqrt2}{8} - \frac{\sqrt2}{8}i$$

$$\mathrm{Res}(f, z_-) = -\frac{\sqrt2}{8} + \frac{\sqrt2}{8}i$$
and so
$$\int_L \frac{1}{z^4+1}\, dz = 2\pi i(\mathrm{Res}(f, z_+)+\mathrm{Res}(f, z_-)) = -\frac{\pi i}{\sqrt 2}$$

EDIT- If you only want to use Cauchy's theorem, then let $C_\pm$ be a small counterclockwise circle around $z_\pm$. Define
$$f_+(z) = (z-z_+)f(z) = \frac{1}{(z^2+\sqrt 2 z+1)(z-1/\sqrt 2 + i/\sqrt2)}$$
Then
$$\int_{C_+} f(z)\, dz = \int_{C_+} \frac{f_+(z)}{z-z_+} dz = 2\pi i f_+(z_+) = 2\pi i \left(-\frac{\sqrt2}{8}-\frac{\sqrt2}{8}i \right)$$
In a similar manner, we obtain
$$\int_{C_-}f(z)\, dz = 2\pi i \left(-\frac{\sqrt2}{8}+\frac{\sqrt2}{8}i \right)$$
Finally,
$$\int_L f(z)\, dz = \int_{C_+} f(z)\, dz+\int_{C_-} f(z)\, dz = -\frac{\pi i}{\sqrt 2}$$

Comment: Thank you very much but I was looking for a Cauchy solution

Comment: @Harton It's not easy for me to *guess* what you mean by "Cauchy solution", but the last line above, just as in my answer, uses Cauchy's Integral Formula (CIF).

Comment: Yes it's my fault, I should have said that I have no idea how resiliums(Res) work

Comment: It's cool, I'm editing my post right now to give a solution using Cauchy's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

There are **two** solutions to $\;z^4+1=0\;$ within the disk enclosed by the circle $\;x^2+y^2=2x\iff (x-1)^2+y^2=1\;$ , which are:

$$\begin{cases}&z_1=e^{\pi i/4}=\frac1{\sqrt2}(1+i)\\{}\\
&z_2=e^{7\pi i/4}=\frac1{\sqrt2}(1-i) =\overline{z_1}\end{cases}$$

Thus, we can make little circles $\;C_1,\,C_2\;$ around the above two poles of our functions, say of radius $\;0.000001\;$ each, and get:

$$\oint_L\frac{dz}{z^4+1}=2\pi i\left[\oint_{C_1}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_1}dz+\oint_{C_2}\frac{g(z)}{z-z_2}dz\right]$$

where

$$f(z)=\frac{z-z_1}{z^4+1}\;,\;\;g(z)=\frac{z-z_2}{z^4+1}$$

Can you take it from here?